# Cannot create custom vuetify theme colors

Tags: vue.js, themes, vuetify.js

In my vuetify.js file I have added the following code in order to create custom theme colors:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: "#abd10d",
    secondary: "#5c40c1",
  }
});
```

However, the themes do not update when I apply them to elements on the site. The primary and secondary themes remain their default colors.

Why aren't my custom theme colors being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `light` (default) or `dark`...

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    light: {
       primary: "#abd10d",
       secondary: "#5c40c1",
    }
  }
})
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/HWrpkuOskr