# How to change color theme in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, colors, themes, vuetify.js

I know these questions are already here, but none of the answer does not work in my case.
I'm trying to change the color in a `vuetify.js` file, but it doesn't work:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    theme:{
        error: '#ffaa2c'
    }
});

export default new Vuetify({
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create custom vuetify theme colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348907/cannot-create-custom-vuetify-theme-colors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it inside the `light` (default) or `dark` theme...

```
    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
      theme: {
        light: {
           error: '#ffaa2c'
        }
      }
    })
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/zeJQGngc6j